# WindowManager: who is creating Documents/Video/Pictures/etc. in home directory

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, window-manager, x-windows

I had Ubuntu-14.04 installed in a minimum configuration, i.e. with no X Windows support. Later I added x-server packages for my card, and a lightweight WindowManager (I don't want KDE or GNOME), so I normally launch X with `startx`, however someone keeps on creating Documents, Desktop, Download, Video, Music etc. directories in my `$HOME`. I thought this isually done by "advanced" desktop environments. What application/daemon can be behind this anyways?